# What does this log mean?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

While my application is running (with a lot of traffic), I see this in error log but I dont even understand what it is about. I guess it's optimizing some configuration but I need a more formal explaination.

```
App 13214 stderr: Trying:
App 13214 stderr:   zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 0  f = 0
App 13214 stderr:       IDAT size = 5698
App 13214 stderr:   zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 0  f = 0
App 13214 stderr:       IDAT size = 5698
App 13214 stderr:   zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 1  f = 0
App 13214 stderr:       IDAT size = 5561
App 13214 stderr:   zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 1  f = 0
App 13214 stderr:       IDAT size = 5561
App 13214 stderr:   zc = 1  zm = 9  zs = 2  f = 0
  zc = 1  zm = 8  zs = 2  f = 0
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 3  f = 0
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 3  f = 0
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 0  f = 1
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 0  f = 1
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 1  f = 1
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 1  f = 1
  zc = 1  zm = 9  zs = 2  f = 1
  zc = 1  zm = 8  zs = 2  f = 1
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 3  f = 1
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 3  f = 1
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 0  f = 2
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 0  f = 2
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 1  f = 2
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 1  f = 2
  zc = 1  zm = 9  zs = 2  f = 2
  zc = 1  zm = 8  zs = 2  f = 2
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 3  f = 2
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 3  f = 2
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 0  f = 3
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 0  f = 3
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 1  f = 3
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 1  f = 3
  zc = 1  zm = 9  zs = 2  f = 3
  zc = 1  zm = 8  zs = 2  f = 3
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 3  f = 3
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 3  f = 3
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 0  f = 4
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 0  f = 4
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 1  f = 4
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 1  f = 4
  zc = 1  zm = 9  zs = 2  f = 4
  zc = 1  zm = 8  zs = 2  f = 4
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 3  f = 4
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 3  f = 4
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 0  f = 5
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 0  f = 5
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 1  f = 5
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 1  f = 5
  zc = 1  zm = 9  zs = 2  f = 5
  zc = 1  zm = 8  zs = 2  f = 5
  zc = 9  zm = 9  zs = 3  f = 5
  zc = 9  zm = 8  zs = 3  f = 5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is verbose output from the [`optipng`](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) utility for shrinking PNG images. You may suppress this output with the `--quiet` option. Though probably one of your gems is calling it and you have little control over whether *it* passes the option.